# How to put picture in footnote correctly on the left?

Tags: footnotes

The question is in the title. Now with MWE below I have this[image]:

with red colour I've underlined important things here. I want picture to be on the left and another text to have formatting like in usual footnote, but with the space fot this picture.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference,a5paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
Hi\footnote{
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=4cm, width = \textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
}

HiHi\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I want the first footnote to look like this:

[image]

where the blue box is my picture. I want to set The textwidth of footnote text to about 0.9 of textwidth of usual text and 0.1 for picture. But if someone can show how to put picture exactly like in this picture (where blue box is out of textwidth), I would glad to see that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `insbox` plain TeX macros package. No minipage required.

```
\documentclass[conference,a5paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}
Hi\footnote{\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\InsertBoxL{0}{\qquad\includegraphics[height=3cm]{traccia-table}}%
\noindent\lipsum[1]}

HiHi\footnote{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*

A code to have an image in the margin of the footnote:

```
\documentclass[conference,a5paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}
Hi\footnote{\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\InsertBoxL{0}{\llap{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{traccia-table}}}%
\mbox{\kern0.1em}\lipsum[1]}

HiHi\footnote{\mbox{\kern0.1em}\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: However, the problem is that "1"-mark is alone on the left. Is it correct? I mean I wanted it to be with the main text like in the second footnote.

Comment: It's normal: the picture is part of the footnote. I don't think it's possible, or it should be very tricky.  A footnote is very close to and item in a list, and it's notoriously hard to insert things in the neighbourhood of lists.

Comment: @Dida: I've found a simple way to insert a picture in the margin of footnotes.. Not perfect, though. Another way would be to see if one can patch `\makefootnote`.